# Using ActionLink and specifying the DELETE Constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm using RestfulRoutes written by Steve Hodgkiss. So far so good but I do have a question. I have a Session Controller that I want to use to destroy a users session when they click the logout button. How can I do this with and action link?

So far I have the following.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Destroy", "Session") %>
```

I need to hit the following route.

Session/{id} and have a DELETE constraint.

I hope this makes sense.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

An anchor tag in HTML can only ever issue a GET, it cannot issue any other verbs (unless you intervene with JavaScript).